# Sending info JavaScript to Android (webview)

Tags: javascript, android

I have a problem with my source code,
I have write a javascript function that I active with a simple button into an HTML page.

The code look like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <base href="http://localhost:8080/testAndroidReturn/" target="_blank">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <div class="panel-title">
                        <h4>teste android</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <input type="text" id="text" value="" />
                    <button type="submit" onclick="saveText()"> submit </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function saveText(){
                alert("coucou");
                AndroidFunction.showToast("COUCOU");
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I have write a project in Android and in the main activity I have write this :

```
package com.bepark.myapplication.app;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        final MyJavaScriptInterface myJavaScriptInterface
                = new MyJavaScriptInterface(this);
        mWebView.addJavascriptInterface(myJavaScriptInterface, "AndroidFunction");

        mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebView.loadUrl("http://10.10.202.184:8080/testAndroidReturn/");
    }

    public class MyJavaScriptInterface {
        Context mContext;

        MyJavaScriptInterface(Context c) {
            mContext = c;
        }

        public void showToast(String toast){
            Toast.makeText(mContext, toast, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void openAndroidDialog(){
            AlertDialog.Builder myDialog
                    = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
            myDialog.setTitle("DANGER!");
            myDialog.setMessage("You can do what you want!");
            myDialog.setPositiveButton("ON", null);
            myDialog.show();
        }

    }

}
```

But when I launch my android application and i click into my `WebView` in the button it do nothing and I have this error message to the log :

```
04-16 04:24:14.458    1212-1212/com.bepark.myapplication.app I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 148 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
04-16 04:24:14.578    1212-1212/com.bepark.myapplication.app I/chromium﹕ [INFO:CONSOLE(22)] "Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'showToast'", source: http://10.10.202.184:8080/testAndroidReturn/ (22)
```

and I don't understand why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding the annotation `@JavascriptInterface` to your public method if you're targetting Jelly Bean OSes.

Hope that helps.